# CRM 2013 Pre Operation Update Plugin not fired from Workflow

Tags: plugins, workflow, crm

I have created a Pre Operation Update Plugin that is Synchronous from the following tutorial.

http://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/crm-2013-step-by-step-update-plugin-tutorial-using-the-crm-2013-development-toolkit/

It works fine when manually saving the entity. However it does not get triggered when a workflow updates the entity.

I do not have any check for Context Depth. Can a workflow call/trigger/fire a synchronous update plugin?

Thank You
Ian